# Salesforce.com workflow could not perform a pending action email not received in sandbox

Tags: sandbox, time-dependent-workflow

When a time-dependent action of a worklow fails, an email is sent to the user who had triggered the worflow. The email subject is "Salesforce workflow could not perform a pending action" and its text body contains the details of the workflow and the record ID for which it failed.

I noticed that such emails are received by users only from Production orgs and not from sandboxes. Is it true ?

Comment: is that my answer works for you?

Answer (score 1):

> You need to check, Setup -> Email Administration -> Email Deliverability options

[image: Email Deliverability]

Change it to `All Emails`

Secondly, email addresses of the users must be valid.

It should work from sandbox.